Using a constructor as parameter to Array.map
I need to map an array of objects to an array of other objects. Here is an example:
class A {}

class B {
  constructor(a: A) {
    // ...do something
  }
}

let a_arr: A[] = [];
// now I want to create a B[] from the A[]

If I use an anonymous function, it compiles without error:
let b_arr: B[] = a_arr.map((item) => new B(item));

But that anonymous function seems useless—I suppose we can directly use the constructor:
let b_arr: B[] = a_arr.map(B.constructor);

Unfortunately, the above line didn't pass compilation:
sh$ tsc t.ts
t.ts:11:28 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: A, index: number, array: A[]) => B'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(value: A, index: number, array: A[]): B'.

11 let b_arr: B[] = a_arr.map(B.constructor);
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in t.ts:11

sh$ tsc --version
Version 5.5.4

Any suggestion?

There's more involved in instantiating objects than just calling the constructor. A simpler case (which also doesn't work for the same reason): let b: B = B.constructor();

Thanks for the comment, @GuyIncognito. In other words, there is no way to eliminate the anonymous function in such cases?

"Any suggestion?" Just... use the anonymous function? It isn't useless, it's doing exactly what you need. Constructors aren't generally callable, you need to new them. Right now this reads like "Instead of console.log(str);, can't I just write str;? Shouldn't JS know that means I want to log it to the console?"

It is technically possible to implement a constructor that is also callable as a regular function, and this kind of construct also exists in native JavaScript classes like String, Number, ...


function B(a) {
    if (!(this instanceof B)) {
        return new B(a);
    }
    this.a = a;
}


const a_arr = ['a'];
const b_arr_reference = a_arr.map(B);
const b_arr_lambda = a_arr.map(a => new B(a));

console.log(b_arr_reference);
console.log(b_arr_lambda);



However, this is not typable as TypeScript because a function as a class is ECMAScript 5 style, and TypeScript does not support it.

You cannot use B.constructor in Array.map because B.constructor is a generic Function and does not match the signature required by Array.map (i.e., (value: A, index: number, array: A[]) => B).
Use an arrow function to explicitly create instances of B:
let b_arr: B[] = a_arr.map(a => new B(a));

reusable mapping function:
const createB = (a: A) => new B(a);
let b_arr: B[] = a_arr.map(createB);

TypeScript doesn't automatically infer the new behavior from a class reference like B or B.constructor when used with map. It requires an explicit function call (a => new B(a)).
